# dropdown refresh with jquery on phonegap. "not jquery mobile"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, drop-down-menu

I want to change the option selected by the code in the dropdown

```
$('#ddd option[value="1"]').prop('selected', true);
```

but it doesnt work for this is mobile phonegap application with jquery.
i think i need to refresh #ddd control but i couldnt succeed with jquery.
i tryed to use jquery and jquery mobile together but i couldnt work it out.
how can i refresh #ddd control with jquery (not jquery mobile)?
thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('#ddd').val('1');
```

Above will set the selected value `<option value="1"></option>`.

You can also trigger change event:

```
$('#ddd').val('1').change();
```